# GWT TreeItems with subitems - overlapping on expanding item

Tags: java, gwt, web-applications, tree

I've been trying to search whole over the Internet, but unfortunately - I couldn't find any answer.

My problem is:
I'm using GWT to create a WebApp. Just clean GWT, without any special widgets etc. I have a simple layout for my app (at north - a bar with buttons, at west - a tree, at center - a tabpanel). The problem is I want to make subitems for items in the tree. It's okay with the tree (I mean the item are adding correctly and the '+' sign appears on the left of item, which has subitems).

The only problem is that, when I'm running app at debug/run or deploy to appengine - expanding the treeitem with subitem is causing overlapping of elements (as shown at s.shot).

http://s17.postimg.org/jpk9yzq5r/gwt_tree.png

And here's my code for tree with items:

```
    final TreeItem trtmNewItem = new TreeItem("Rejestr kontrahentów");

    trtmNewItem.setHeight("30px");
    trtmNewItem.setState(true);
    /* TreeItem treeItem = trtmNewItem.addItem("Dodaj kontrahenta");
    treeItem.setHeight("30px"); */
    trtmNewItem.addItem("Dodaj kontrahenta");


    final TreeItem trtmNewItem_1 = new TreeItem("Faktury przychodzące");
    trtmNewItem_1.setText("Faktury przychodzące");

    trtmNewItem_1.setHeight("30px");
    trtmNewItem_1.setState(true);

    final TreeItem trtmNewItem_2 = new TreeItem("Faktury wychodzące");

    trtmNewItem_2.setHeight("30px");
    trtmNewItem_2.setState(true);

    final TreeItem trtmNewItem_3 = new TreeItem("Umowy");

    trtmNewItem_3.setHeight("30px");
    trtmNewItem_3.setState(true);

    final TreeItem trtmNewItem_4 = new TreeItem("Kalendarz");

    trtmNewItem_4.setHeight("30px");
    trtmNewItem_4.setState(true);

    Tree tree = new Tree();
    tree.setAnimationEnabled(false);
    dockLayoutPanel_3.add(tree);
    tree.addItem(trtmNewItem_5);
    tree.addItem(trtmNewItem);
    tree.addItem(trtmNewItem_1);
    tree.addItem(trtmNewItem_2);
    tree.addItem(trtmNewItem_3);
    tree.addItem(trtmNewItem_4);
```

This is really annoying and I don't want to use any other widget library (maybe some day, when this app will work fine and stable...).

Thank you in advance!
Regs
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not set height on tree items. Use CSS to style your tree by setting a line-height on a tree or top-margin (better, if text can wrap in your tree items) on tree items.

For example, you can add this to your CSS file:

```
.gwt-Tree .gwt-TreeItem {
    margin-top: 6px !important;
}
```